# creating dynamic textbox in wpf according to location

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, textbox, controls

I'm trying to create dynamically text box in WPF. It is very essential that I will have the flexibility to determine where the text box will be - in pixel level.
I have found many answers which use stackpanel to create "run-time" text box - but couldn't find how to construct it according to specified location.

the textbox has to be "word wrap" and I'm using a button click event to create the text box

this is the code for now, I really don't know which methods or properties will be helpful. 
thanks :)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox x = new TextBox();
            x.Name = "new_textbox";
            x.TextWrapping= TextWrapping.Wrap;
            x.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
            x.AcceptsReturn = true;
            x.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 TextBox x = new TextBox();
 x.Name = "new_textbox";
 x.TextWrapping= TextWrapping.Wrap;
 x.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
 x.AcceptsReturn = true;
 x.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 0, 0);
 HouseCanvas.Children.Add(x);
 Canvas.SetLeft(x, 20);
 Canvas.SetTop(x, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to place it in a Canvas, if you care about pixel placement of the textbox itself.  You'll need to use x.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pixelX) [and .RightProperty, etc...] to get the position exactly right.  Having not done this myself, I'd guess that you need to put the canvas in the right Z-order (on top), and make it transparent.  There may also be issues with events, depending on the z-order.  Good luck!

-Kev